# Jboss vs tomcat ( clearing the shadows over java ee support )

Tags: tomcat, jboss, jms, ejb, application-server

Just another question around this old subject, from an experience perspective, what is it really that makes someone choose Jboss or another application server against a tomcat ?

I am not talking about the java ee support, i mean, Tomcat can make all the java ee api works simply by adding some librairys and some little configuration, so if that's possible, why should i use Jboss, why the majority prefer Jboss to Tomcat when it comes to using : JMS, EJB...

Comment: What defines "lightweight"?

Comment: You're right, it may be missleading in this situation, let's just say ...agains a Tomcat ?

Answer (score 0):

Just my point of view working with JBoss in production for several years...

With Wildfly stable, Redhat needs several months to harden the projects for reaching something maintainable and production ready. And even with this, you are facing issues in production.

Most of them show up when using EE features in conjunction, in a more complex scenario and under heavy load.

Every API has its own spec. Specs try to be complete and consistent (which is not reality). If you have to put things together, you will end up with a common ground of garanteed behavior and a lot of observed behavior, possibly changing with versions evolving in time.

With an applicationserver, you may probably observe that things will better match to each other, using common ways for cross cutting concerns like configuration, monitorin, logging, patch management, security, ...

Your approach, just putting some APIs together and doing some configuration will work for small applications, not production ctritical and not meant to be maintained in the future.